# Python ThreadPoolExecutor().map with instance methods

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary

Lets say we have the following code:

```
class Pipe:
    def run(self, id):
        return f'Running pipe {id}'

pipes = [Pipe() for n in range(5)]
ids = [n for n in range(5)]
```

How can we execute method `Run()` for each Pipe object passin `ids` into each `Run()` method?
Kind of below makes no sense:

```
with f.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map([p.run for p in pipes], ids)
```

Comment: executors from the concurrent module accept the same notation as `functools.partial` when submitting jobs to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method is a function that expects an instance to be passed in as its first argument (typically named `self`). Normally that happens automatically, `obj.method(x)` gets translated into `type(obj).method(obj, x)` behind the scenes. But you can do that kind of call yourself if you need to.

I think you want something like this, which uses the unbound `Pipe.run` as the function and lets the `map` code iterate over the `pipes` and `ids` sequences in parallel:

```
with f.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    results = executor.map(Pipe.run, pipes, ids)
```

Comment: Yes, that is what I expected. Thanks.